# Why isn't possible to append a same child in two dom element?

Tags: javascript

I just notice I couldn't do

```
var d1 = document.createElement('div');
var d2 = document.createElement('div');
var p = document.createElement('p');

d1.appendChild(p); // d1 has p now
d2.appendChild(p); // d2 has p now
// but where is p in d1 ?
```

Some would say it's logic, but well, when I first noticed that I thought how uncool it was.

Why isn't that possible ?

Comment: Can you have one person in two cars at the same time ? What's not natural here ?

Comment: You can clone it and put it under the second parent.

Comment: @DenysSéguret but a dom is not a car. I mean I am aware that `p` has one reference, moving that reference from one place to another one has some effect but my question is why doesn't the language create duplicate references for multiple bindings ?

Comment: @HoschNok False and false. 1) If you append a node with jQuery you also move it. 2) there's a native `cloneNode` method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is a **tree** structure.

When you append an element, you change its parent.

A node, in the browser, is much more than just the text inside your P (that string could be shared, in fact). It also has a position, dimensions, a visibility, receives events that could have been fired in child elements, propagate events to its parent, and so on. Everything here depends on the position in the tree. Just like would many CSS selectors. It doesn't make a lot of sense to imagine it's the same element at two places, it's better to think about it as two nodes, with maybe some identical content.

If you want to have the same content at two places, you have [to clone it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Comment: Ok I see, clone... but cloning will remove the ability to fire a custom-event in several part of my dom at one time. I need to loop on the different clones as to trigger the custom-event one after another.

Comment: Yes but iterating on elements having one class is fast and easy : `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myClass'), function(){ ...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's `appendTo()` method](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) inserts "every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target". Try this:

```
p.appendTo(".div-class1, .div-class2")
```

Comment: Please insert more descriptions for your answer.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

for AppendChild same element multiple times , we can use this way :

```
//main function
function appendChildMultiple(parent) {
  //check function argument is an element
  if (parent.nodeType !== undefined) {
    const pTag = document.createElement("p");
    pTag.innerText = "This is the appended element";
    //finally append child to parent
    parent.appendChild(pTag);
  }
}
```

and :

```
// target the wrapper and create test elements
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const d1 = document.createElement("div");
const d2 = document.createElement("div");
//append test elements to wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(d1);
wrapper.appendChild(d2);

//use appendChildMultiple function
appendChildMultiple(d1);
appendChildMultiple(d2);
//we appended "pTag" multiple times
```

if we use Functions , we can AppendChild same element multiple times whitout cloneNode

https://codepen.io/kiumad/pen/eYMNKYa