# Appending a preloaded image several times within a loop

Tags: javascript, image

```
window.preloadShips = function(){
    window.shipImages.omega = new Image();
    window.shipImages.omega.src = "shipIcons/omega.png";
}

//later 

    for (var i = 0; i < this.primary.systems.length; i++){
        var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.className = "iconContainer";
            td.appendChild(window.shipImages.omega);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
```

when doing this, what happens is that only the TD in the table with hold the img, all other TDs will be empty.

a) why is that ?

b) whats the best way to circumvent the issue ?

- thanks

Comment: What is the value of `this.primary.systems.length`?

Comment: it doesnt matter how long it is, it can be 3 or 13. Fact is, only the last appeneded TD holds the img. At least thats my observation.

Comment: Provide the full source code, corresponding html as well so. Also you are not calling preloadShips function anywhere in the above provided code.

Comment: Did you even read what i described ? Problem is solved thanks to KnightNiwrem who was helpful ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you are pointing to the same child DOM element in your loop. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667088/why-isnt-possible-to-append-a-same-child-in-two-dom-element) should help you solve your issue.