# Want to use appendChild multiple times

Tags: javascript

Whoops, accidentally asked this in the code review section =D Let's try again.

I'm trying to create a small div inside a section every time I click a button.

The section is id="grid" and the button has a simple onclick="generateGrid()"

my code:

```
 var div = document.createElement('div');

 function generateGrid() {

 document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(div);
}
```

This works, but only once. I've tried researching the answer and several people seem to have similar but more complex situations and I'm unable to figure this out.

Basically I just want to click the button, and another div pops up within the section.

So initially it would look like this:

```
<section id="grid">
</section>
```

Then after I click the button it looks like this:

```
<section id="grid">
<div></div>
</section>
```

Then after I click the button again, it looks like this:

```
<section id="grid">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

And so on and so forth.

Right now the first button click works great, but nothing happens after that on clicks.

Trying to avoid jQuery and just use vanilla JS if possible.

Later I plan to use a loop to generate the divs based on the clientWidth but I'm starting simple =]

Is there something I need to do with the appendChild or should I be using something else completely? I've also tried playing with innerHTML but wasn't able to make that work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have *the same* HTML element added as a child multiple times. That's why it "works only once".

Comment: It all boils down to the fact that DOM elements are objects and not strings. You created `div` element object only once, so appending the same child to the same `section` element has no effect.

Comment: "Trying to avoid jQuery and just use vanilla JS if possible" - if something is possible with jQuery then it must be possible with vanilla JS. There's no other possibility since jQuery itself is written in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the div element inside the function.

```js
function generateGrid() {
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<section id="grid">
a
</section>
<button onclick="generateGrid()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you create `div` outside the function , that `div` is the same node, no matter how many times you  call the function & you cannot add the same node to the same parent multiple times. An almost similar problem is  describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667088/why-isnt-possible-to-append-a-same-child-in-two-dom-element). When you create div inside the function , it is creating a new node which is getting added to the parent

```js
function generateGrid() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var nodeTxt = document.createTextNode('Div');
  div.appendChild(nodeTxt);

  document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<section id="grid"></section>
<button type='button' onclick='generateGrid()'> Click</button>
```