# Add a paragraph in multiple html elements that are the same using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add `<p>Hello World</P>` , using javascript, in two div elements in html that are the same.

So I have this div elements :

`<div></div><div></div>`

What I tried is this :

`let p = document.createElement('p');`
`p.textContent = "Hello World";`
`document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach((divElement) => {element.appendChild(p);})`

But it only adds it to one of the div elements, how can I make it so that I have it in both div elements ? no jquery please

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have more than one element with the same id.  Use a class.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even if I use a class and it has nothing to do with the ID, it still doesn't work. I just want to add a paragraph to for example all div elements that have no attributes. How do I do that ?

Comment: You also have a typo: (divElement) => {divElement.appendChild(p)}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there are 2 problems: the first is that you are using the same ID for multiple elements, the second is that you are creating a single DOM object for more than one element. You can solve it by using classes and creating a paragraph each time you want to append it.

EDIT: This answer provide an explanation of why you cannot append the same child twice: [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667088/why-isnt-possible-to-append-a-same-child-in-two-dom-element)

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach((el) => {
   let p = document.createElement('p'); 
   p.textContent = "Hello World";
   el.appendChild(p);
})
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  Also OP has a typo in their closure